# Clarification of bash trap

Tags: bash

I'm currently going trough bash tutorial :

http://linuxconfig.org/Bash_scripting_Tutorial

And I came to the part which I'm having troubles to understand :

```
#!/bin/bash
# bash trap command
trap bashtrap INT
# bash clear screen command
clear;
# bash trap function is executed when CTRL-C is pressed:
# bash prints message => Executing bash trap subrutine !
bashtrap()
{
    echo "CTRL+C Detected !...executing bash trap !"
}
# for loop from 1/10 to 10/10
for a in `seq 1 10`; do
    echo "$a/10 to Exit." 
    sleep 1;
done
echo "Exit Bash Trap Example!!!"
```

Where exactly do you specify ok trap `CTRL+C`? This line `trap bashtrap INT` ? does INT mean something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`INT` is `SIGINT` or "Interrupt from keyboard", the signal that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> causes.

If you're on Linux, see the manpage `signal(7)` for more information about `SIGINT` and other signals.

Comment: Maybe you can add the Linux command on how to access the man page